# Difference in ranking in pages from UK and standard google.co.uk?

Tags: seo, google-search, geotargeting

My website doesn't seem to rank for many phrases in the standard search results on `google.co.uk` and by standard I mean not filtered.

When filtered (Search tools -> Country > UK) I rank reasonably well.

What exactly is the common denominator for ranking parallel in both of these searches?

Answer (score 1):

When searching in "standard search" (ie. no filter) then you are searching the "world", as opposed to sites only from the UK. So, it sounds as if there are simply more websites elsewhere in the world (ie. outside the UK) that are ranking higher than yours.